# What is the fastest way to flatten an array of arrays in ocaml?

Tags: arrays, functional-programming, ocaml

What is the fastest way to flatten an array of arrays in ocaml?  Note that I mean arrays, and not lists.

I'd like to do this linearly, with the lowest coefficients possible.

Comment: `Array.to_list` followed by `Array.concat` ...

Comment: That sounds quadratic because of Array.concat.  I want to do this linearly with the lowest coefficients possible.

Comment: then do it in an imperative fashion with loops ... (of course I doubt that Array.concat would be implemented that stupidly but alas do what you want)

Comment: `Array.concat` is properly linear in the sum of the lengths of the component arrays; it calculates the total length and then fills it from the start, iterating over the component arrays. In fact, as of 4.x, it's implemented in C (the 3.12 version is straightforward OCaml code that you can easily check yourself).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OCaml Standard Library is rather deficient and requires you to implement so many things from scratch. That's why we have extended libraries like Batteries and Core. I would suggest you to use them, so that you will not face such problems.

Still, for the sake of completeness, let's try to implement our own solution, and then compare it with a proposed `fun xxs -> Array.(concat (to_list xxs))` solution.

In the implementation we have few small problems. First of all in order to construct an array we need to provide a value for each cell. We can't just create an uninitialized array, this will break a type system. We can, of course use `Obj` module, but this is rather ugly. Another problem, is that the input array can be empty, so we need to handle this case somehow. We can, of course, just raise an exception, but I prefer to make my functions total. It is not obvious though, how to create an empty array, but it is not impossible:

```
 let empty () = Array.init 0 (fun _ -> assert false)
```

This is a  function that will create an empty polymorphic array. We use a bottom value (a value that is an inhabitant of every type), denoted as `assert false`. This is typesafe and neat.

Next is how to create an array, without having a default value. We can, write a very complex code, that will use `Array.init` and translate `i`th index to `j`'th index of `n'th` array. But this is tedious, error prone and quite ineffective. Another approach would be to find a first value in the input array and use it as a default. Here comes another problem, as in Standard Library we don't have an `Array.find` function. Sic. It's a shame that in 21th century we need to write an `Array.find` function, but this is how life is made. Again, use `Core` (or `Core_kernel`) library or `Batteries`. There're lots of excellent libraries in OCaml community available via `opam`. But back to our problem, since we don't have a find function we will use our own custom solution. We can use `fold_left`, but it will traverse the whole array, albeit we need to find only the first element. There is a solution, we can use exceptions, for non-local exits. Don't be afraid, this is idiomatic in OCaml. Also raising and catching an exception in OCaml is very fast. Other than non local exit, we also need to send the value, that we've found. We can use a reference cell as a communication channel. But this is rather ugly, and we will use the exception itself to bear the value for us. Since we don't know the type of an element in advance, we will use two modern features of OCaml language. Local abstract types and local modules. So let's go for the implementation:

```
let array_concat (type t) xxs =
  let module Search = struct exception Done of t end in
  try
    Array.iter (fun xs ->
        if Array.length xs <> 0
        then raise_notrace (Search.Done xs.(0))) xxs;
    empty ()
  with Search.Done default ->
    let len =
      Array.fold_left (fun n xs -> n + Array.length xs) 0 xxs in
    let ys = Array.make len default in
    let _ : int = Array.fold_left (fun i xs ->
        let len = Array.length xs in
        Array.blit xs 0 ys i len;
        i+len) 0 xxs in
    ys
```

Now, the interesting part. Benchmarking! Let's use a proposed solution for comparison:

```
let default_concat xxs = Array.concat (Array.to_list xxs)
```

Here goes our testing harness:

```
let random_array =
  Random.init 42;
  let max = 100000 in
  Array.init 1000 (fun _ -> Array.init (Random.int max) (fun i -> i))


let test name f =
  Gc.major ();
  let t0 = Sys.time () in
  let xs = f random_array in
  let t1 = Sys.time () in
  let n = Array.length xs in
  printf "%s: %g sec (%d bytes)\n%!" name (t1 -. t0) n

let () =
  test "custom "  array_concat;
  test "default" default_concat
```

And... the results:

```
$ ./array_concat.native
custom : 0.38 sec (49203647 bytes)
default: 0.20 sec (49203647 bytes)
```

They don't surprise me, by the way. Our solution is two times slower than the standard library. The moral of this story is:

1. Always benchmark *before* optimizing
2. Use extended libraries (core, batteries, containers, ...)

### Update (concatenating arrays using Base)

With the base library, we can concatenate arrays easily,

```
let concat_base = Array.concat_map ~f:ident
```

And here's our benchmark:

```
./example.native 
custom : 0.524071 sec (49203647 bytes)
default: 0.308085 sec (49203647 bytes)
base   : 0.201688 sec (49203647 bytes)
```

So now the base implementation is the fastest and the smallest.

Comment: what's the answer if you use Core :D ?

Comment: @David天宇Wong, see the updated answer